# Can't get the correct result using each() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used each function to get the values of input boxes and select boxes to do some calculation but it seems that the calculation is working fine in module 1 section only the rest modules nothing is happen for some reason I don't know what it is till now:-

here is a demo of what is happening:-

http://jsfiddle.net/r2shhxhj/

and here is my javascript code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Scal").click(function() {
   var sumSc = 0;
   var sumSg = 0;
   var sumSgSc = 0; 
        $('[name^="Sc"], [name^="Sgrade"]').each(function () {
   sumSc += +$(this).val();
            sumSg = $(this).val() * $('[name^="Sgrade"]').val();
   sumSgSc += +sumSg
          });
   var total = sumSgSc/sumSc
   console.log(total);
      $('#Sres').val(total);
  });
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're finding both credits and grades, when the inner logic expects `this` to be a credit number.

Having *found* a credit, you want to find the next grade; instead, you're pulling up *all* grades, and getting `val()` from that, which will always return the value of the first match.

Instead, search for *just* credits. Then, find the parent `li`'s next sibling, and search for the grade within *that*.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Scal").click(function() {
    var sumSc = 0;
    var sumSg = 0;
    var sumSgSc = 0;
    $('input[name^="Sc"]').each(function() {
      var grade = $(this).closest('li').next('li').find('[name^=Sgrade]');
      sumSc += +$(this).val();
      sumSg = $(this).val() * grade.val();
      sumSgSc += +sumSg
    });
    var total = sumSgSc / sumSc
    $('#Sres').val(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="f"> <a data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="pop" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-icon="home" title="Home" href="index.html">Home</a>

    <h1>BENG & BSc</h1>

  </div>
  <form id="form">
    <div id="GPA1" class="GPA1">
      <div class="BENG" id="N1">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
          <li style="border:none">
            <h1>Module 1:</h1>

          </li>
          <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
            <label for="Sc1">Credits:</label>
            <input type="number" step="0.01" name="Sc1" id="Sc1" class="Sc" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
          </li>
          <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
            <label for="Sgrade1" class="select">Grade:</label>
            <select name="Sgrade1" class="Sgrade" data-theme="f" id="Sgrade1">
              <option value="-1">—</option>
              <option value="4">A</option>
              <option value="3.7">A-</option>
              <option value="3.3">B+</option>
              <option value="3">B</option>
              <option value="2.7">B-</option>
              <option value="2.3">C+</option>
              <option value="2">C</option>
              <option value="1.7">C-</option>
              <option value="1.3">D+</option>
              <option value="1">D</option>
              <option value="0">F</option>
            </select>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="BENG" id="N2">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
          <li style="border:none">
            <h1>Module 2:</h1>

          </li>
          <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
            <label for="Sc2">Credits:</label>
            <input type="number" step="0.01" name="Sc2" id="Sc2" class="Sc" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
          </li>
          <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
            <label for="Sgrade2" class="select">Grade:</label>
            <select name="Sgrade2" class="Sgrade" data-theme="f" id="Sgrade2">
              <option value="-1">—</option>
              <option value="4">A</option>
              <option value="3.7">A-</option>
              <option value="3.3">B+</option>
              <option value="3">B</option>
              <option value="2.7">B-</option>
              <option value="2.3">C+</option>
              <option value="2">C</option>
              <option value="1.7">C-</option>
              <option value="1.3">D+</option>
              <option value="1">D</option>
              <option value="0">F</option>
            </select>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="BENG" id="N3">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
          <li style="border:none">
            <h1>Module 3:</h1>

          </li>
          <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
            <label for="Sc3">Credits:</label>
            <input type="number" step="0.01" name="Sc3" id="Sc3" class="Sc" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
          </li>
          <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
            <label for="Sgrade3" class="select">Grade:</label>
            <select name="Sgrade3" class="Sgrade" data-theme="f" id="Sgrade3">
              <option value="-1">—</option>
              <option value="4">A</option>
              <option value="3.7">A-</option>
              <option value="3.3">B+</option>
              <option value="3">B</option>
              <option value="2.7">B-</option>
              <option value="2.3">C+</option>
              <option value="2">C</option>
              <option value="1.7">C-</option>
              <option value="1.3">D+</option>
              <option value="1">D</option>
              <option value="0">F</option>
            </select>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="BENG" id="N4">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
          <li style="border:none">
            <h1>Module 4:</h1>

          </li>
          <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
            <label for="Sc4">Credits:</label>
            <input type="number" step="0.01" name="Sc4" id="Sc4" class="Sc" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
          </li>
          <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
            <label for="Sgrade4" class="select">Grade:</label>
            <select name="Sgrade4" class="Sgrade" data-theme="f" id="Sgrade4">
              <option value="-1">—</option>
              <option value="4">A</option>
              <option value="3.7">A-</option>
              <option value="3.3">B+</option>
              <option value="3">B</option>
              <option value="2.7">B-</option>
              <option value="2.3">C+</option>
              <option value="2">C</option>
              <option value="1.7">C-</option>
              <option value="1.3">D+</option>
              <option value="1">D</option>
              <option value="0">F</option>
            </select>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="BENG" id="N5">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
          <li style="border:none">
            <h1>Module 5:</h1>

          </li>
          <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
            <label for="Sc5">Credits:</label>
            <input type="number" step="0.01" name="Sc5" id="Sc5" class="Sc" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
          </li>
          <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
            <label for="Sgrade5" class="select">Grade:</label>
            <select name="Sgrade5" class="Sgrade" data-theme="f" id="Sgrade5">
              <option value="-1">—</option>
              <option value="4">A</option>
              <option value="3.7">A-</option>
              <option value="3.3">B+</option>
              <option value="3">B</option>
              <option value="2.7">B-</option>
              <option value="2.3">C+</option>
              <option value="2">C</option>
              <option value="1.7">C-</option>
              <option value="1.3">D+</option>
              <option value="1">D</option>
              <option value="0">F</option>
            </select>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="buttons">
      <li class="ui-body ui-body-b" style="border:none">
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
          <div>
            <button type="button" id="Sadd" name="Sadd" data-theme="f">Add Module</button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-body ui-body-b" style="border:none">
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
          <div>
            <button type="button" id="Sremove" name="Sremove" data-theme="f">Remove Module</button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
          <label for="Sres">Your GPA:</label>
          <input type="number" step="0.01" name="Sres" id="Sres" value="" data-clear-btn="true" readonly>
        </li>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-body ui-body-b" style="border:none">
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
          <div>
            <button type="button" id="Scal" name="Scal" data-theme="f">Calculate</button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-body ui-body-b" style="border:none">
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
          <div>
            <button type="reset" data-theme="d">Reset</button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```